# Can't access google sheet that is in a shared drive using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to read and then write to a google sheet that's in a shared google drive using their api but cant access the file thats in a shared drive. It cant find the file for some reason. I got it working to the point where it can read the basic file that the quickstart gives us but when I access my file it doesnt work. Heres the code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'MY ID'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        print('Name, Major:')
        for row in values:
            # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The is the error it gives me

```
HttpError 400 when requesting {Link to my sheet}
```

Comment: I think that the method of spreadsheets.values.get can retrieve the values from the Spreadsheet on Shared Drive. So can you confirm that you have the permission of the reader or writer to the Shared Drive again? And, when you modify the range from `'Class Data!A2:E'` to `"'Class Data'!A2:E"`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: I am added in the shared drive and can access through the account that i used for the program. When i modified that line nothing changes i still got error 400

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested your request, no error occurs. The values can be retrieved from the Spreadsheet on the shared Drive. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.